# Issues with server-side classic ASP code within client-side <script> tags

Tags: javascript, vbscript, asp-classic

I was working on troubleshooting a page (in classic ASP), and stumbled upon the following piece of code within the `<head>` tag (Note #1: I am using VS2012 as my editor; note #2: I did *not* write this code):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var EditHelp = '<%=Session("editHelp")%>';  
        <%If Request.Form.Count Then%>
            window.opener.location.replace(window.opener.location);
        <%End If%>                                                              
    </script>
```

VS is telling me that the `<script>` tag does not like any of the server-side `<% %>` code (it's telling me, "Syntax error"), and the page is not rendering correctly.  It seems to be okay everywhere else outside the `<script>` tags.  VS does not seem to recognize the `<% %>` tags within the `<script>` tags.  They seem to be okay everywhere else.

I've never come across this before.  Can someone enlighten me as to why this is causing a problem?

Comment: Note (mainly to myself): I found this link that might be helpful: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Classic_ASP_Design_Mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say the page isn't rendering correctly, do you mean inside Visual Studio itself in the design view? Does it still run correctly through IIS using the normal ASP classic interpreter? If so I would put it down to Visual Studio's syntax highlighting/error checking not being identical to the interpreter itself and that complex edge cases can throw false positive errors within Visual Studio. I've seen things like that happen in the past with modern versions of Visual Studio and always found that as long as the page works correctly through IIS they can safely be ignored inside Visual Studio.

The only part of your original code that I can see a potential issue with is that if `Session("editHelp")` contains a `'` it will corrupt the JavaScript code. Doing `Replace(Session("editHelp"), "'", "\'")` or similar may well be safer if that string isn't already sanitised elsewhere in your code.

Other than that I can't see a problem with it, but to 'eliminate it from your enquiries' so to speak, you could replace all the ASP blocks with suitable dummy static content and run it that way, to see if your rendering issue persists. If it's still there, you can safely eliminate this. If it goes away, more investigation is in order?

Comment: No.  It is not rendering correctly in the browser (in this case, Firefox v. 25.0).  I'm trying to figure out why it is not rendering correctly, and happened to stumble across the scenario that I described above.  Basically, I'm trying to eliminate this as a potential cause of my problem.

Comment: When you say it isn't rendering correctly, how do you mean exactly?

Comment: There is no styling (just the basic barebones HTML tag behavior).  It's like the CSS and stylesheets are ignored.  I'm actually not worried about that at all; that is not the point of my question (and it is -not- the question I am asking).  The point of this question is, how is server-side classic-ASP code (within <% %> brackets) supposed to behave within a <script> tag?

Comment: Expanded my answer. To answer your direct question - it should be fine, I have seen and written quite a bit of old ASP classic code that uses server side code to generate JavaScript without issues. The issues you're seeing are likely two of VS's built in parsers and syntax highlighters throwing a wobbly as they try to interact. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Yeah, that does make sense.  I think it's more of a case of the VS editor throwing me.  I just wanted to make sure that I eliminated the issue as a potential cause of the bigger issue.  Thanks!

Comment: I can't be absolutely sure about your case, of course; you can always carry out the suggestion from the last paragraph of my edit to be absolutely certain, and sanitising and performing `Server.HTMLEncode()` on the string on output would be good practice, but my gut says your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Yeppers -- turned out that it was.  I threw in a stylesheet link that was missing, and sure enough, the page rendered better.  Not quite "correct" -- I do need to tweak it a bit, but it's progress. :-)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!